# How to add WebGL Carousel Effect to the 3d models?

Tags: reactjs, animation, three.js, slider, react-three-fiber

I was creating a r3f slider and I injected some mesh materials inside the slider and its actually slide when I use my mouse to the left and right with react-use-gesture , I made a very simple slider but what I want to know how can I add a shader effect on every slide so it can trigger on the 3d model when the state change , I created a simple codesandbox for this , if someone can give me some tips how can I achieve this , that would be appreciated !

[3d carousel ( codesandbox )](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-tree-v9tqgy?file=/src/App.js)